# Measure of union of uncountable set

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to understand or prove a conjecture:

Let $U$ be an uncountable set of Lebesgue measure zero. Suppose for each element of $U$, there exists a set $Z_i$ with Lebesgue measure zero. Then, $\bigcup_{i} Z_i$ is a set of Lebesgue measure zero.

Any hint or proof? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take any measure zero set which has the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$-it can be for example the Cantor set $C$. Then there is a bijection $f$ between $C$ and $\mathbb{R}$. Then for each $a \in C$ we can assosiate $f(a)$ and $\bigcup_{a \in C}f(a)=\mathbb{R}$. The reason is that two sets with the same cardinality may be very different from the measure theoretic point of view: in other words arbitrary bijection need not preserve zero-measure sets.

Comment: A side comment: This sort of argument - building up the union in continuum-many pieces - is necessary, in a precise sense. It is consistent with ZFC (but independent!) that the union of *fewer than* continuum-many measure-zero sets has measure zero. Obviously this follows from CH, but it turns out that it can be true even if e.g. $\vert\mathbb{R}\vert=\aleph_{17}$.

Comment: But I think that you have to assume your set to be measurable-in contrast to countable case where every coutable set is measurable and of measure zero (for Lebesgue measure).

Comment: I don't think that's right - I believe what I wrote is correct. Certainly you can have $\vert\mathbb{R}\vert=\aleph_{17}$ and every set of reals of size $<\aleph_{17}$ is null. But maybe my previous comment needs a measurability hypothesis, let me check.

Comment: Can we say these sort of counterexamples exist if and only if the cardinalities of  $\mathbb{R}$ and $C$ are equal. I mean, is it possible to come up with a counterexample where there is no bijection between  $\mathbb{R}$ and $C$? Thanks

Comment: I mean instead of $\mathbb{R}$, suppose we are in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $C\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ be uncountable.

Comment: But in fact the cardinalities of $C$ and $\mathbb{R}$ or even $\mathbb{R}^n$ are all the same and equal to continuum-regardless of the continuum hypothesis. So I don't know whether I understood your question correctly: do you mean that now we take an uncountable (but less than continuum) union of sets of measure zero and ask whether we can produce the set of positive measure? Then the answer is negative-see Noah Schweber comments.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I am not a math major and I was thinking that cardinalities are different when the dimensions are different, but now I almost understand. Actually I don't know the definitions of continuum-many and fewer than continuum-many, but I am trying to find that on the web.

Comment: @Noah Schweber I think your side comment is useful for my specific problem. Could you please define continuum-many and fewer than continuum-many for me? or just give me a reference. Thanks

Comment: @Mohkam7 "Continuum-many" just means "as many as there are real numbers": when I say there are continuum-many elements of $A$, I mean there is a bijection between $A$ and $\mathbb{R}$. Cardinality can be surprising - for instance, there is no bijection between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$, but there **are** bijections between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$. And there is a bijection between $C$ and $\mathbb{R}$. However, it is possible that there is a set of reals which is uncountable, but not in bijection with $\mathbb{R}$ (that is, of "intermediate" cardinality). (cont'd)

Comment: The statement that there is no such set is the **continuum hypothesis**, and is known to not be provable or disprovable from the usual axioms of set theory, ZFC.

Comment: Sorry, I am still a bit confused. If cardinalities of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ are the same, why $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ is a set of Lebesegue measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$? Actually, I somehow understand, but I cannot digest all of these together. If I define a counting measure instead of the Lebesgue measure, is there any chance that the conjecture would work? Thanks truebaran @NoahSchweber

Comment: @Mohkam7 Measure and cardinality are, unfortunately, largely unrelated: we can have a size-continuum set with zero measure (e.g. Cantor set). Having positive measure means at the very least that the set must be uncountable (and, if measurable, then size continuum), but just knowing the cardinality of a set tells you nothing about its measure. Re: counting measure, there is no set which is uncountable but has counting measure zero, so I'm not even sure what you're asking there.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** This is not true.

You can use any non-measurable set to build a counterexample if you index it with the elements of the Cantor set.

Comment: This isn't even true if every set is measurable! Just take $U$ to be the Cantor set, $f$ a bijection between $U$ and $\mathbb{R}$, and $Z_i=\{f(i)\}$ for $i\in U$. Then $\bigcup Z_i$ is all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I am still a bit confused by this answer, to be honest - unless I'm missing something, bringing non-measurable sets into the picture just makes things more complicated.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I suppose I could accomplish the same with any set of non-zero measure... but the point is that you can take a union if null sets to get a set that is not "measurable with measure zero".